# how to change order of columns in data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data, column

I have added several new columns in my DE but now all new columns shows up at the end. it will be useful if i can re-arrange the columns in a specific order.

can i do that? how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's currently not possible to rearrange columns in a Data Extension.

The Contact Builder version of the Data Extension UI has some additional features not found in Email Studio, but re-ordering isn't among them.

Comment: ok thank you Adam